# Precedent for disabled Kings

Tags: game-of-thrones

Has there been any disabled King in the history of Westeros? Or any Kings who suffered from a bout of gout which rendered them unable to walk for a long time (possibly permanently)?

Comment: Well Prince Doran Martell of Dorne was stuck in a wheelchair.

Comment: In support of @Edlothiad's comment, the Dornish rulers style themselves "princes" even when they are the local equivalent of kings. So Doran Martell is effectively a semi-disabled "king".

Answer (score 11):

[Aegon II](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_II_Targaryen) suffered disabilities as a result of war injuries. He sat the throne till his death.

During [his battle](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Battle_at_Rook%27s_Rest) with his second cousin Princess [Rhaenys](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhaenys_Targaryen_(daughter_of_Aemon)) Targaryen, his Grace suffered grievous wounds. Half his body was burnt by dragon fire, with bones shattered due to his fall. He remained comatose for that period of [the war](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Dance_of_the_Dragons) until [King's Landing fell](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Fall_of_King%27s_Landing) to his [sister's](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhaenyra_Targaryen) forces and he escaped posing as a commoner.

Even though he remained twisted and bent due to unhealed wounds, he still recovered some in hiding. Afterwards he [took his sister's castle of Dragonstone](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Fall_of_Dragonstone) during which he had to fight his cousin Princess [Baela](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Baela_Targaryen) Targaryen and her dragon. Aegon won this battle too but he fell and broke both his legs again. His Dragon died soon afterwards. It was rumoured that along with his legs, His Grace lost the ability to procreate as well though it was never proven and later he intended to take another wife.

Eventually his sister's star waned, she was forced out of King's Landing by rioting locals and was arrested and executed by Aegon. When Aegon returned to the Red Keep, he couldn't climb the steps to the throne so he held court from a wooden bench at the foot of the throne while using a blanket to hide his twisted legs.

If we speak of mental disabilities we've [Aegon III](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aegon_III_Targaryen). Aegon III had severe depression, PTSD (Tip of the hat to Adamant) low self-worth<sup>1</sup> and social anxiety because he'd been through the trauma of seeing his uncle Aegon II's dragon devour his [mother](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhaenyra_Targaryen), having his [father](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Daemon_Targaryen) killed at hand of his [cousin](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Aemond_Targaryen) and losing four of his brothers in the civil war<sup>2</sup>. He spoke little, ate very little and took little interest in anything<sup>3</sup>. Councillors had to beg his grace to eat during the regency, otherwise he'd simply forget about it and brood quietly in some dark corner of the Red Keep or keep staring to the sky for hours. And he hated being touched. His Queen [Jaehaera](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jaehaera_Targaryen) was similarly depressed as she'd suffered through her father (the very same Aegon II) being poisoned, her [mother](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Helaena_Targaryen) committing suicide because of depression, her [twin brother](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Jaehaerys_Targaryen_(son_of_Aegon_II)) murdered before her very eyes, [her youngest brother](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Maelor_Targaryen) killed by a mob, and losing both her uncles to forces loyal to her [aunt](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Rhaenyra_Targaryen). She'd start weeping if someone spoke loudly in her presence, weep while she was awake, weep while she was sleeping and wet her bed. The little Queen was so panicked and terrified on her wedding day that the Grand Maester had to put sweetsleep in her milk to calm her nerves and make sure she didn't faint or start weeping in front of the whole realm. It didn't do her mental health any favours when the regents forbid her [grandmother](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Alicent_Hightower), the last person she was close to, to meet her after the Dowager Queen Alicent was discovered telling Jaehaera to slit her husband's throat to avenge her brothers and parents. Both the King and his Queen were broken beyond repair and the Queen would eventually kill herself (Although it is debated to this day whether she'd truly mimicked her mother's death to escape her pain or was she thrown out of her tower by Lord Regent [Unwin Peake](https://awoiaf.westeros.org/index.php/Unwin_Peake) who'd hoped to marry his daughter to the boy King he served).

We've also had King Aerys II who was clearly mad and King Maegor who was possibly unhinged as well.

Other than Kings, as Ed says, we have Prince Doran Martell who had severe gout and couldn't walk so he had to be taken everywhere in a palanquin or a wheelchair.

---

<sub>**1.** Aegon came from a long line of warriors and conquerors. He'd grown up idolising his elder half-brothers who'd all grown into brave warriors. His father Prince Daemon, considered both terror and wonder of his age, was a most puissant warrior who was awarded Queen Visenya's sword *Darksister* by King Jaehaerys I for his prowess. And yet when the war came, All three of his half-brothers had died fighting bravely for their mother (Even his half sister Princess Baela fought to the last moment when Aegon II came to take Dragonstone), his father died a heroic death after an epic fight against his cousin and Vhagar, his sister Baela killed Aegon II's dragon and left him crippled. And what did he do? He abandoned his younger brother Viserys in hands of the foe to escape on his little dragon. And that wasn't all, when his uncle's men surrounded his mother, he once again failed to defend her. Aegon was ashamed that he'd chosen to run rather than trying to protect his younger brother. He was ashamed that his valiant brothers had died and he, in his mind the most worthless of them all, was sitting the Iron Throne which should have been theirs. He was ashamed that he could not protect his mother. Of course Aegon was judging himself too harshly, he was only a little boy himself, no one expected him to defend his younger brother or his mother.</sub>

<sub>**2.** His 4th brother and only full sibling, Prince Viserys hadn't actually died, rather he was held hostage in Lys. The King and the realm had all presumed him dead since he'd been missing for long time. When Lord Alyn Velaryon eventually traced down Viserys and brought him back, it is said that for the first time after the war, some joy returned to the life of the Broken King.</sub>

<sub>**3.** He did try to show interest once when he came uninvited to a small council meeting and asked Lord Regent some questions about matters at hand, hoping to learn about ruling. Lord Regent brusquely told him that he had no time to answer a child's annoying questions. Aegon simply left and never returned to the council except on his 16th birthday when he came to fire his entire regency council as he was now a man grown. As King in his own right, even though he remained brooding, socially crippled and quiet he stood by the words he said to the council as he took throne. *"I mean to give the smallfolk peace and food and justice. If that will not suffice to win their love, let Mushroom make a progress. Or perhaps we might send a dancing bear. Someone once told me that the commons love nothing half so much as dancing bears. You may call a halt to this feast tonight as well. Send the lords home to their own keeps and give the food to the hungry. Full bellies and dancing bears shall be my policy"*</sub>

Comment: Aegon III specifically sounds like PTSD to me. Although if some of those traits dated before his trauma it sounds like he could be on the autism spectrum (sensory hypersensitivity, low social interaction, etc).

Comment: @Adamant No he was a bright cheerful boy before the war. I believe you are correct in your assessment.